# Uncaught ReferenceError: Typewriter is not defined

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

I have added a script for a typewriting feature I want to add on the banner of my website but for some reason on jsfiddle.net it works perfectly fine but when published it doesn't work.

On opening the console on Chrome I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Typewriter is not defined

```
<script>
var app = document.getElementById('notificationBar');
var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {
    loop: true,
    cursor: "",
});
typewriter.typeString('MESSAGE1')
    .pauseFor(2500)
    .deleteAll()
    .typeString('MESSAGE2')
    .pauseFor(2500)
    .deleteAll()
    .typeString('MESSAGE3')
    .pauseFor(2500)
    .start();
</script>
```

Not really sure what I should do to fix this as I am just getting used to Javascript and this is my first script project. Any suggestions would help ;)

Comment: Have you loaded the script containing `Typewriter` class/constructor?

Comment: Well where is the definition of the Typewriter constructor?

Comment: Nothing in your code indicates that it _is_ defined. Can you share the link to the JSFiddle?

Comment: Probably related to the order of the script tags or bad path to the typewriter source file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked around and found the `script` you need to use:

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect@2.3.1/dist/core.js"></script>`

```js
var app = document.getElementById('notificationBar');
var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {
    loop: true,
    cursor: "",
});
typewriter.typeString('MESSAGE1')
    .pauseFor(2500)
    .deleteAll()
    .typeString('MESSAGE2')
    .pauseFor(2500)
    .deleteAll()
    .typeString('MESSAGE3')
    .pauseFor(2500)
    .start();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect@2.3.1/dist/core.js"></script>
<div id="notificationBar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the CDN in the **Resources** section
**OR**
simply add it as a script in the HTML:

```html
<script src="path/to/resource.js"></script>
```